# C++ how to pass unique_ptr to function and still benefit from polymorphism?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

I have the following class definitions:

```
class A {...}
class B : public class A {...}
```

and an owner class definition:

```
class C {
    A* a;
public: 
    C (A* a) { this->a = a; }
}
```

Then When I try to call the following, everything is fine:

```
B* b = new B();
C(b);
```

But then I have the following owner class definition:

```
class C {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
public: 
    C(std::unique_ptr<A>& a) { this->a = std::move(a); }
}
```

And when I try to call the following, I get a compiler error saying cannot convert from unique_ptr of B to unique_ptr& of A:

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b(new B());
C(b);
```

I do realize that std::unique_ptr& and std::unique_ptr is not the same. But I'm not sure what the standard protocol is for passing unique pointer to an owning class.

I tried the following:

```
class C {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
public: 
    C(std::unique_ptr<A> a) { this->a = std::move(a); }
}
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr<B> b = std::make_unique<B>();
C(std::move(b));
```

This works but feels counter intuitive, because part of the purposes of using unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr is to get that performance increase from not having to copy memory address. But in this case, instead of copying memory address, it's creating a brand new unique_ptr to just pass it by value, only to toss it away after the function goes out of scope.

Note: I'm using VS C++11 compiler

Comment: give func function a unique_ptr: func(a.get());

Comment: According to the documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) `std::make_unique` is C++ 14 (thus **you are already using C++ 14** features). And otherwise, I don't think there are any major change in `std::unique_ptr` between C++ 11 and 14. Your `C` constructor should probably be: `C(std::unique_ptr<A>&& a) : a(std::move(a)) {}`.

Comment: @sailfish009 class C needs to take ownership of the pointer so your answer is not gonna work.

Comment: @Phil1970 sorry, make_unique is a C++14 feature. I have my own version of make_unique which mimics that, so I should have stated that. I will make the change to the original question. Is passing-by-rvalue-reference also a C++14 feature?

Comment: @jahithber if you pass func(a.release()) then your class can take ownership of the object.

Comment: @Abhishek then what's the point of using unique pointers? why not just use regular pointer reference and set the original pointer to nullptr?

Comment: @jahithber : I was just replying to the comment in which you said, a.get() won't work because you want your class take ownership.
You C lass could be :
class C {
  std::unique_ptr<A> m_a;
public:
  C(A * a) :
    m_a(a)
  {}
};

Advantage : You don't have to call delete so you can avoid problems with memory leak.

Comment: @Abhishek ok I see. The way I see this is that, when you are passing by pointer to a function, there's no expectation that the ownership will be transferred. So the caller code could potentially call delete on the pointer and cause problems. Functions with unique pointers as their input parameters are explicitly saying that it's gonna do something about the uniqueness of the pointer, so there is the expectation of transferring ownership. so maybe the function could be written like this: public: C(A*& a) { m_a = a; a = nullptr; }

Comment: @jahithber I agree. It is semantically more clear when you pass unique_ptr to a function. I was extending on the previous comment where you said a.get() won't work because you want your class C to take the ownership.

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade your compiler. C++ 11 is already 6 years old and as it was the most major change, you should consider upgrading if you are not at least using VS 2015 as the compiler has improved a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass unique pointers by mutable reference. You will have bugs such as this one.

Indeed the solution is to pass by value:

```
class C {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a;
public: 
    C(std::unique_ptr<A> a) { this->a = std::move(a); }
}

// ...

auto b = std::make_unique<B>();
C(std::move(b));
```

> This works but feels counter intuitive, because part of the purposes of using unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr is to get that performance increase from not having to copy memory address.

No. The advantage of unique ptr is that they are a zero overhead abstraction over a pointer with a unique ownership.

Shared pointer have a cost. Each time they are copied, they are performing atomic ref-count. This hurts the cache and is not a negligible overhead. Also, shared pointer hide who owns who. The number of owners are determined at runtime, which makes the code harder to think about.

By the way, copying an address has negligible overhead. A reference is most of the time implemented in term of a pointer. Copying a raw pointer has the same cost as passing by reference. Since `std::unique_ptr` is a zero overhead abstraction, copying (or moving) a unique pointer has the same cost as copying a raw pointer, which in turn is about the same cost as passing by reference. You don't have to worry about the performance of copying pointers.

> But in this case, instead of copying memory address, it's creating a brand new unique_ptr to just pass it by value, only to toss it away after the function goes out of scope.

Creating a brand new `unique_ptr` is the same cost as copying a memory address. Unlike other popular languages, C++ object are on the stack by default, offering the same performance as dealing with native types.

---

If you worry so much about performance, compile with optimization, profile your code and benchmark. Any statement about performance is meaningless unless you measure it. If you inspected the assembly output of the compiler, you'd notice that they are **[exactly the same](https://godbolt.org/g/U8XnKU)**.

Disclaimer: I did not compile using clang in the live example, because it elided the whole code away even on `O2`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, how do you feel about passing by rvalue-reference instead? Would that be more efficient instead of by value? And if it is, is there any pitfall to avoid?

Comment: @jahithber passing by rvalue reference is again, the same most as creating a new value. Try for yourself! I linked you a magnificent website that you can see what the compiler do with your code. But there are pitfalls: passing by reference don't transfers ownership. You must use move to transfer by rvalue reference, but your value might not be actually moved, since the function receiving the rvalue is responsible to either actually move the value or not. I would never recommend passing unique_ptr around by rvalue reference.

Comment: @jahithber Also, again, if you really want to have optimal code, write benchmarks and profile it. Any other discussion about performance is speculation unless you mesure it. The website I showed you proved that performance is the same. If the assembly output is different and you worry about performance, *profile your code*.